# Not able to make archive ios app for publish

Tags: xamarin, build, msbuild, archive, visual-studio-mac

I have used the latest visual studio(8.3) and Xcode 11 in mac.
I am able to run my project on both configurations​ like debug and release.

but when try to archive ios app for making IPA it failed...for archiving it's taking 1+ hr and at the end, it fails.

Logs

---

> MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol:
>   _Xamarin_iOS_MapKit_MKDirectionsResponse__ctor_intptr. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native
>   libraries are properly linked in. MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native
>   linking failed, undefined symbol:
>   _Xamarin_iOS_MapKit_MKDirectionsResponse_get_ClassHandle. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and
>   native libraries are properly linked in. MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native
>   linking failed, undefined symbol:
>   _Xamarin_iOS_MapKit_MKDirectionsResponse_get_Routes. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native
>   libraries are properly linked in. MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native
>   linking failed, undefined symbol:
>   _Xamarin_iOS_MapKit_MKDirections_CalculateDirections_MapKit_MKDirectionsHandler.
>   Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced
>   and native libraries are properly linked in. MTOUCH : error MT5210:
>   Native linking failed, undefined symbol:
>   _Xamarin_iOS_MapKit_MKDirections__cctor. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are
>   properly linked in.
>
> this type of 66454 Error(s) I am getting.
>
> ---
>
> please help me.

Comment: What's your Link behavior?  Check the points listed in the document: [mtouch-errors#mt5210](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#mt5210-native-linking-failed-undefined-symbol--please-verify-that-all-the-necessary-frameworks-have-been-referenced-and-native-libraries-are-properly-linked-in)

Answer (score 0):

Try just building the application then the .ipa file will be in bin\Iphone\release